# Random Variable $X_{\min}$ and $X_{\max}$ for absolute steady distributions

Tags: calculus, stochastic-calculus

In my homework I need to find the density function of $X_{\max}$ and $X_{\min}$ where

$$X_{\min} = \min\{X_1(w), ..., X_n(w)\},$$

$$X_{\max} = \max\{X_1(w), ..., X_n(w)\}$$

and where the $X_i$, $i = 1,\ldots,n$, are i.i.d. random variables with a given density function f and distribution function F which are not relevant here.

There is a hint:

"How do you express $[X_{\min} > t]$ under usage of $[X_1 > t], ..., [X_n > t]$ for absolut steady distributions?"

How do I go about this? I have absolutely no clue.

Comment: What is meant by "absolute steady distribution?" That is not a term I have encountered beffore.

Comment: It might be continous distribution. I am a german native so i just translated it word for word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the following facts:
$$ \mathbb{P} (X_\min \le x) = 1- \mathbb{P} (X_\min > x) = 1-\mathbb{P}(X_1 > x, \ldots, X_n > x). $$

For $X_\max$ you can write directly
$$ \mathbb{P} (X_\max \le x) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 \le x, \ldots, X_n \le x). $$

Recall that, if the $X_i$'s are independent, you can further develop the last term (in both the two equations).

Comment: Can i develop them to $n \cdot P(X \leq x) = n \cdot F(t)$ (for $X_{max}$)?

Comment: What do you mean by $X$? Are the $X_i$'s i.i.d. random variables?

Comment: Yes , they are independent identically distributed.

Comment: Ok, so edit the question and insert also such information. Since they are independent, $\mathbb{P}(X_1\le x,\ldots,X_n\le x) = \mathbb{P}(X_1\le x) \cdots \mathbb{P}(X_n\le x)$, and since they are identically distributed....

Comment: So it has to be $n \cdot \mathbb{P}([X \leq x])$ doens´t it? Because each of the $\mathbb{P}([X_i \leq x])$ has the same probability?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: And why exactly can i reshape the $X_{\min}$ and $X_{\max}$ like that? I dont get exactly why you can say $P(X_{\min} \leq x) = 1 - P(X_1 > x, ..., X_n > x)$? How do i know that $X_{\min}$ is that?

Comment: You know the [complement rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_event#Complement_rule), moreover, the minimum of $n$ things is greater than $x$ only when _all of them_ are greater than $x$.

Comment: Sorry, i might have been not specific enough. I mean why is $P(X_{\min} > x) = P(X_1 > x, ..., X_n > x)$?

Comment: Exactly because of what I said in the previous comment, i.e., the minimum of $n$ things is greater than $x$ only when all of them are greater than $x$. That is, $X_\min > x$ if and only if $X_i > x$ for every $i$.